# How to stop the program from reading through every line and pop out message of each line?

Tags: java, oop

I am doing the login GUI.The problem that I faced is when the program read the username and password from my notepad, it will pop out the message for each line which saved in txt file. For example, there are three set of username and password in my txt file, when the program read through the first line of txt file, if the first set of username and pasword key in is match, it will pop out"login successful", but if the second set of password and username is keyed in, it will pop out "Incorrect password and username", after you pres ok,it then just pop out"Login successful". Guys, I need your help. Thankss

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

```
    String inputUser = input1.getText();
    String inputPass = input2.getText();
    File loginf = new File("oop.txt");


       try{
           Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("oop.txt"));


           while(read.hasNext()){
               String user = read.next();
               String pass = read.next();
               read.next();

           if(inputUser.equals(user) && inputPass.equals(pass)){    
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login Sucessful");
                   break;
           }

           else if(!inputUser.equals(user)&&!inputPass.equals(pass)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Username and Password");
           }
           }



           read.close();
       }
       catch (FileNotFoundException qwerty){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find a text file");
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file till you find a match, set a flag or store the values you need and break out of the loop, then decide which message to display

```
boolean youShallNotPass = true;
while(read.hasNext()){
    String user = read.next();
    String pass = read.next();
    read.next();

    if(inputUser.equals(user) && inputPass.equals(pass)){    
        youShallNotPass = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(!youShallNotPass){    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login Sucessful");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Username and Password");
}
```

Comment: `youShallNotPass` is funny but makes it unnecessary hard to read. ;) +1 anyway.

Comment: True, maybe `youBeGood`?  It's 430pm, I have a headache and my job sucks, this is all the humor I can get :(